# command line tool for viewing files of arbitrary file-type?

Tags: command-line

Is there a command line tool (e.g. called "view") that will select a program to open / view a file with automagically based on the file extension and/or other hints to the format?

Comment: If this is *not* what you want, please comment, or [edit] your question, and we will reopen it.

Answer (score 0):

Use `man -k mime` (search for `man` pages related to `mime`) to find

```
mimeopen (1p)        - Open files by mimetype
mimetype (1p)        - Determine file type
```

and many other interesting `man` pages.